# Trouble stopping a "Do Until" loop in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So my new issue is that I cannot get the following code to stop looping. It seems as though my "do until element is nothing" line may not be completely accurate as the button I am attempting to click is not showing a "nothing" value at the end of the run. Here is the code with a brief description of the issue.

```
Sub SearchBot()


Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim y As Integer
Dim result As String

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate "https://www.searchiqs.com/nyalb/Login.aspx"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

objIE.document.getElementById("btnGuestLogin").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate").Value = "07/11/2017"

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtThruDate").Value = "07/13/2017"

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cboDocGroup").Value = "DBA"

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_cmdSearch").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

y = 1

' brings up a table of results. I need to click on the view button and get the info from that page

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_btnView_0").Click


Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

' element ID's are hidden for those looking to help

result = Trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = result

'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

y = y + 1


' I would love to direct link to the next search result here but the link does not change between pages so I click the next button

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

 ' I believe this is where the issue occurs

Do Until objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext") Is Nothing

result = Trim(objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_lblDetails2").innerText)

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = result

y = y + 1

' when the next page button is visible, it goes to the next page. When it is dimmed, the code continues. It doesn't stop unless I manually stop it. It takes the final page and repeats the process infinitely. 

objIE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").Click

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Loop


' I end up with a few good results in the beginning and then the final result repeats until I eventually stop the script.

End Sub
```

this is the html reading when the button is visible

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnNext" title="Next Document" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext" style="width: 35px;" onclick="SaveDocListSelected();" type="submit" value=">>">
```

this is the html reading when the button is dimmed

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnNext" title="Next Document" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext" style="width: 35px;" type="submit" value=">>">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you may need to reset the document, as it will be "new" I think...

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your are testing for the wrong thing: whether the button is disabled or not, it's still there on the page.  You need to check for the classname="aspNetDisabled"